# plotCI: how to overlay plots of two variables

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot populations of predators and of prey over time, with confidence intervals. I can plot these two separately, how to plot on same graph?

```
#take mean, number, and create se of prey(d)
d.means=tapply(mydata$prey,mydata$week, mean)
d.n=tapply(mydata$prey,mydata$week, length)
d.se=tapply(mydata$prey,mydata$week, sd)/sqrt(d.n)
#plot with se using plotrix
plotCI(as.numeric(row.names(d.means)),d.means,d.se,ylim=c(0,400),pch=19,gap=0,xlab="Week",ylab="d, w population")




 #take mean, number, and create se of predator(w)
w.means=tapply(mydata$pred,mydata$week, mean)
w.n=tapply(mydata$pred,mydata$week, length)
w.se=tapply(mydata$pred,mydata$week, sd)/sqrt(w.n)
#plot with se using plotrix
plotCI(as.numeric(row.names(w.means)),w.means,w.se,ylim=c(0,400),pch=19,gap=0,xlab="Week",ylab="d, w population")
```

Comment: Are you open to answers that use ggplot instead of plotCI? Is there a particular reason you want to use that function?

Comment: Yes of course. I tried but was overwhelmed with the syntax and unable to decipher enough of the ggplot2 tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

After the first plot, use the code below before plotting the next plot:

```
par(new=T)
```

Make sure that you set the xlim and ylim to accommodate both plots. And you will need to use the options axes=F and ann=F.

These graphical features are discussed in detail in the ebook "R Fundamentals & Graphics". You might want to use it as a desk reference.

Comment: is that your book that you keep plugging? Secondly, a better way would be to use the add parameter in plotCI

Answer (score 1):

```
#take mean, number, and create se of prey(d)
d.means=tapply(mydata$prey,mydata$week, mean)
d.n=tapply(mydata$prey,mydata$week, length)
d.se=tapply(mydata$prey,mydata$week, sd)/sqrt(d.n)


 #take mean, number, and create se of predator(w)
w.means=tapply(mydata$pred,mydata$week, mean)
w.n=tapply(mydata$pred,mydata$week, length)
w.se=tapply(mydata$pred,mydata$week, sd)/sqrt(w.n)
```

Here you have created all the variables you need but to plot them using ggplot you need them to be in a tall dataset with an variable indicating if they are predator or prey. I also added a time variable, I think yours would be week.

```
x=data.frame(means=c(w.means,d.means),
             n=c(w.n,d.n),
             se=c(w.se,d.se),
             role=c(rep("pred",length(w.n)),rep("prey",length(d.n))),
             time=c(1:length(w.n),1:length(d.n))
             )
```

I don't know exactly what your data look like so here is a fake one I cooked up just to illustrate the format.

```
      means  n         se role time
1 0.9874234 10 0.16200575 pred    1
2 1.4120207 12 0.08895026 pred    2
3 2.7352516  8 0.07991036 pred    3
4 1.1301248 11 0.05481813 prey    1
5 2.4810040 13 0.28682585 prey    2
6 3.1546947  9 0.22126054 prey    3
```

Once the data are in this nice format using ggplot is really pretty easy.

```
ggplot(x, aes(x=time, y=means, colour=role)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-se, ymax=means+se), width=.1) +
  geom_line()
```

That gives this:

[image]

Comment: This is great. A further question: how to connect the top of CI points with lines, connect bottom CIs with lines, shade in between these lines. I have prey and up to three predators, over 10 weeks, and I think graphically this would be helpful (especially because my data was very good!).